# SQL - Select rows with same value in one column and choose the one with specific value in other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started learning SQL and ran into a problem that I can't solve on my own.

I have the following table:

| id | project | field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10301 | A | field_10200 |
| 10302 | null | field_10201 |
| 10303 | A | field_10202 |
| 10400 | null | field_10300 |
| 10401 | null | field_10301 |
| 10500 | null | field_10400 |
| 10502 | B | field_10212 |
| 10505 | A | field_10301 |
| 10506 | B | field_10301 |

Now I want to output only the IDs where the field belongs to project A or null but not both.

The output should look like this:

| id | project | field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10301 | A | field_10200 |
| 10302 | null | field_10201 |
| 10303 | A | field_10202 |
| 10400 | null | field_10300 |
| 10500 | null | field_10400 |
| 10505 | A | field_10301 |

Comment: Last row (10505, A, field_10301) shouldn't exist in the output since field_10301 exists with project A and null!

Comment: You are right and I have it wrongly formulated in my text. It should show the output only if the field belongs to project A alone, null alone or A if both A and null. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
select *
  from Table t
 where t.project = 'A'
    or (    t.project is null
        and not exists(select * from Table t2
                        where t2.project = 'A' and t2.field = t.field)
       )
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer solved your issue then you should accept that answer.  This helps future questioners have similar issues and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.

Comment: And also motivation for the answerer :)